Can grub pass a PXE script to iPXE?
I'm trying to configure a system to boot the Ubuntu live system from a PXE server.  The DHCP server on the network doesn't support PXE.  The machine has grub and I've installed iPXE.  I can select the Network Boot option from the grub menu, press Ctrl+B and manually set up the PXE options to get it to boot.  Is there a way to automate this so that selecting the grub menu option will automatically run a PXE script when it loads iPXE?  I don't mind if this is a script that's stored on a local filesystem or if grub passes a URL for a script to iPXE.

Can't you just get a reasonable DHCP server, ideally on the same box that hands out the PXE?

@tink - it may come to this.  It's part of the pain of working from home, I have a home-grade router that doesn't let me customise this sort of thing.  I've already taken DNS away from it, it might be time to take DHCP away from it as well.  The annoying thing is that I only wanted to network boot the Ubuntu installer because I didn't have a USB memory stick to hand or not one fast enough to make the process bearable.  Several days later, I'm still trying to get PXE boot working.

If you cant get the entries added to the DHCP server to support pxe, then you will have to bypass network booting.
An easy way to do this is to compile or patch ipxe to embed an ipxe script in the binary.  The ipxe package includes tools to both patch existing binaries and include a path to a script on the make command line when building ipxe to do this.
Once you have an ipxe with an embedded script, you can start it any way you like, including normal EFI boot or refind or grub, and start it like any other efi (or even legacy) boot binary.

Hmmm, okay, thanks.  I'll stop beating my head against it at least.

I have various usb sticks with one or several of grub, refind, or ventoy as the primary boot and all of them have vanilla and modified versions of ipxe on them as well.
